# How to best Sidewire this 8 hole quickwire outlet

Tags: wiring, receptacle

I’m going around replacing a few old outlets that are in sad shape. I went to change this one and noticed it is an 8 hole outlet. Cutting the power to this outlet only cut the power to one set of wires, so i know it is linked somewhere down the line to another breaker.

Wondering what is the best way to rewire this on a sidewire.

Oh, it is not grounded if that helps. For those wondering about the marks on the outlet, yes this outlet failed, rather dramatically as well. But was replaced with another exact outlet in the same quickwire fashion after examining the wires to ensure that they were not damaged tehmselves.

[image: Outlet][image: Outlet1]

Answer (score 1):

As far as the wiring, look at the neutral and hot side for a "tab" that has been broken off.

If neither tab is broken off, there is a serious wiring problem - don't put them on a 240V breaker. You have 2 circuits bridged together somewhere. Likely not here.

If either side has a broken tab, you must figure out which circuit breaker power these, and they must be "handle-tied".  Since handle-ties are hard to find, you can replace both breakers with a single "2-pole 240V" breaker which has a built-in handle-tie.

If one tab is broken off, you have a **multi-wire branch circuit** and you can read more on what they are. Read carefully on those, and take the time to identify each one in your panel and make sure it is handle-tied or on a 240V 2-pole breaker with a built-in handle tie.

If both tabs are broken off, that is fine but you still need that handle-tie.

That is an obsolete socket type which has only backstabs.  It is also the "el cheapo" type socket.  The newest el-cheapo (50 cent) sockets provide 4 backstabs and 4 side screws.

However, your easiest time will be using the "spec grade" ($3) sockets. They provide a back-wire scheme called "screw-and-clamp" where tightening the screw clamps the wires. It is all the more important to tighten the screw to spec, since too little won't clamp the wires well.

Comment: So a look at the old outlet revealed that the tabs on either side were intact. This being the same as the one replacing it. These were all controlled from our screw fuse panel on 15A fuses. Today, this fuse panel was replaced with 15A breakers by an electrician. None of the breakers popped when the power was restored, other then one outlet in the kitchen that was a split outlet (which the old electrician our building used forgot to remove the tab to split it.) Once the electrician split that kitchen outlet today, all was well afterwards.

Comment: @tdotman that makes sens. But still those breakers need to be tied for safety, so the next guy doesn't get nailed when trying to work on the split kitchen outlet.